# Jenkins not cloning git repository

Tags: git, jenkins

I was trying to run a Jenkins job which checks out code from a Git repository. I am using Git plugin and Credentials plugin for configuring it. However when I run the job, it is failing with the following error.

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Apps\Jenkins\jobs\Test\workspace
Wiping out workspace first.
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository http://mygitrepo/project/myproject.git
> C:\Apps\Git\bin\git.exe init C:\Apps\Jenkins\jobs\Test\workspace\test # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://mygitrepo/project/myproject.git
> C:\Apps\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
> C:\Apps\Git\bin\git.exe config --local credential.helper store --file=\"E:\TEMP\git2078292677000877754.credentials\" # timeout=10
> C:\Apps\Git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress http://mygitrepo/project/myproject.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/configurator/*
> C:\Apps\Git\bin\git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'configurator'
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'configurator'
Finished: FAILURE
```

How do I fix this issue?

!Git configuration[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOs2Y.png)

**Update**
The issue was with stash. Stash was throwing some error when Jenkins was cloning.

Comment: What is your git configuration in Jenkins ? Are you sure that you have 'configurator' repo in your git ?

Comment: yes. My repository name is configurator.

Comment: Could you show your git configuration in Jenkins ?

Comment: Please also provide your project git settings. Which Plugin do you use? I noticed that git plugin works not so sweet like the multi-VCS-plugin

Comment: I got it working. The issue was with stash. It was throwing an error when Jenkins was trying to clone the repository.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I Guess your Git Repository configuration is Wrong in your project.

[image]

Posssible solution;-
Try to create an local git repository and give path upto .git file.

Or if you are storing at remote location like in github,stash etc..
Use url,pswd-obtained from repository management software

Comment: I got it working. The issue was in stash. It was throwing an error when Jenkin was trying to clone.